# RadWindow.Close All() function

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, telerik, wcf-ria-services

I saw there is a `Radwindow.CloseAll()` function in the RadWindow control for ASP.NET AJAX. Is there a similar function in the RadWindow control for Silverlight?

I am building a Silverlight 4 application with 1 page and multiple childwindows that I converted to RadWindows in code C#. The app works like a wizard type app, on the page the user chooses what he wants to do and then the 1st window would ask for more information then the user clicks next and go to the 2nd window and so on and so on, until the last window that only shows and prints the information the user have just entered/selected in the previous windows. Everything works well. But how do I close all these windows, to go back to the first page, only by clicking on the close button on the last window?

I have disabled the close and rezise buttons on all the windows exept the last window. Al these windows are reliant on each other because of data (form a sql database) purposes.

Please any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the RadWindowManager : `RadWindowManager.Current.CloseAllWindows`